# Retrofit & Interceptor - Android, using Kotlin with OKHTTP if the API response body size is very large

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, okhttp, interceptor

I have built an interceptor and I have one API call response that returns a series of emojiis over and over again, with a size of over 25MB, so the app crashes when this particular network call is made. I want to exclude the emojiis in the response entirely, or just reduce the size down to one emojii.

I have written this interceptor and viewed the documentation: https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-response-body/as-response-body/

How do I return this value as the response body in Kotlin? Any help for the retrofit Interceptor would be appreciated.

````
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.Response
import okhttp3.ResponseBody
import okio.IOException

abstract class Interceptor() : Interceptor {
  /** This interceptor compresses the HTTP request body.  */
  @Throws(IOException::class)
  override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
    val originalRequest: Request = chain.request()
    val response: okhttp3.Response = chain.proceed(originalRequest)

    if (response.body != null) {
      val byteResponse = response.body?.contentLength()!!
      // return  response.body?.contentLength:Long= -1L):ResponseBody
      if (byteResponse > 500000) {
        val shorter =( byteResponse -1L)
        shorter.asResponseBody(). // this line is the problem as it can't just be cast to a response body return
      }
    }
    return response
  }
}```
````

Answer (score -1):

Can GSON help here? If you are looking to read the response in an easier and cleaner way.

Example: https://medium.com/@pypriyank/consuming-rest-api-in-android-using-retrofit-and-gson-20268aadf0eb

Comment: question is about interceptor but answer is related to how to use headers in call.